# Is there a plugin that can replace WP comments with Facebook comments as used by TechCrunch?

Tags: comments, facebook

I've long been impressed by TechCrunch's Facebook comments, is there a plugin for WordPress self-hosted websites which achieves the same effect?

Comment: There are several Plugins to integrate Facebook comments into WordPress. Can you clarify what *specifically* you like/want to emulate from TechCrunch's implementation?

Comment: To clarify: the reason that I ask is that, otherwise, you're just going to get a long list of Facebook comment-integration Plugins. It would be far more useful to know the **specific features, styles, etc.** that you want, in order to tailor more-specific answers.

Comment: I suppose I want the exact-same implementation as TechCrunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the official Facebook plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/

supported both by Facebook and Automattic. Give it a spin.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use the **Facebook Comments for Wordpress** plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-comments-for-wordpress/

Comment: Any reason why you stopped?

Comment: I decided to go with disqus (http://disqus.com/) instead. I simply wanted my users to have the option to use other social media accounts other than just Facebook to be able to comment. The plugin works great and I never did have any kind of problem with it. My one gripe is that comments made with it does not show up in the comment count in the Wordpress admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

the best one is here this plugin for wordpress i user on my website
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disqus-comment-system/

Comment: This doesn't seem like an answer to the question, honestly. It seem like an answer to "What is your favorite comment plugin?" So, can you explain why this might provide comments that look/work just like _TechCrunch's FaceBook comments_?